# C# TCP Connection saving clients and broadcasting to them

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

For practicing I wanted to create client and server applications to simulate a lobby.

Therefore, in the server-application I accept incoming connections, create a ClientInfo object containing the TcpClient object, usernames, id, etc. and the methods for sending and receiving data, and store that ClientInfo object in a List in my lobby class. When the user does something like chatting, the message is being sent to the server and broadcasted to all available clients.

The problem I have is:
The first client connects. Broadcasts go to DefaultUser1.
The second client connects. Broadcasts go to DefaultUser2 + DefaultUser2.

As you can see, the first Client is not receiving data anymore, nor can the Server receive data from him. Somehow the data in the list must be corrupted. Here is the relevant bit of code:

Accepting incoming conenctions and creating the ClientInfo object and storing it to the lobby:

```
 while (mWorking)
            {
                TcpClient client = mListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                mNumberOfClients++;
                Console.WriteLine("New Tcp-Connection with client: " + client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
                ClientInfo newInfo = new ClientInfo(client, mNumberOfClients);
                mLobby.AddClient(newInfo);
            }
```

The ClientInfo constructor:

```
public ClientInfo(TcpClient client, int clientNumber)
    {
        mClient = client;
        mClientNumber = clientNumber;
        mUsername = "DefaultUser" + mClientNumber.ToString();
        mStream = client.GetStream(); 

        mEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    }
```

The sending method in ClientInfo:

```
 public void Send(String message)
    {
        mCurrentMessage = message;
        Thread sendThread = new Thread(this.WriteTask);
        sendThread.Start();
    }

    private void WriteTask()
    {
        byte[] data = mEncoding.GetBytes(mCurrentMessage);
        byte[] sizeinfo = new byte[4];

        sizeinfo[0] = (byte)data.Length;
        sizeinfo[1] = (byte)(data.Length >> 8);
        sizeinfo[2] = (byte)(data.Length >> 16);
        sizeinfo[3] = (byte)(data.Length >> 24);

        mStream.Write(sizeinfo, 0, sizeinfo.Length);
        mStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

Relevant code in the lobby class:

```
private static List<ClientInfo> mClients;
    private static processDel mProcessDel;
    public Lobby(processDel del)
    {
        mProcessDel = del;
        mClients = new List<ClientInfo>();
    }

    public void AddClient(ClientInfo client)
    {
        mClients.Add(client);
        client.Listen(mProcessDel);
        Broadcast("UJOIN§" + client.username + "$");
    }

public void Broadcast(String message)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mClients.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Broadcasting to " + mClients[i].username);
            mClients[i].Send(message);
        }
    }
```

I also tried the broadcasting with foreach, same result. The processDel is a delegate method i need for processing the received data. Receiving is handled by a seperate thread for each client.

Comment: Well i am both happy and sad. You just found the issue i was searching for so long and I was too dumb to realize. Many thanks, you were right, the ClientInfo attributes are all static. Maybe you can also give me some hints to thread-safety in an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess, it seems that you misunderstood what `static` means in C#.

`static` means that the method or field is part of the type, rather than the instance of a type. So if all of your fields are static, you don't actually have any instance data, and all the state is shared across all instances of your class - so the second client overwrites all the data associated with the first client as well. The solution is simple - just remove the `static`s, and you should be fine.

Other than that, your code has some thread-safety issues. Most types in .NET are not thread-safe by default, and you need to add appropriate locking to make sure that consistency is maintained. This is more of a topic for CodeReview, perhaps, so I'll just note the first things that come to mind:

- `Send` always starts a new thread to send the message. However, this also means that if it's called twice in succession under just the right conditions, it can completely corrupt your TCP stream - for example, the first thread might write the length data, then the second writes its length data before the first writes the actual data and you're in trouble. It's also possible that you'd just send the second message twice, since you're passing the text to send through a field.
- `List<T>` isn't thread-safe. That means that you can only safely use it from a single thread - it's not entirely clear from your code, but it seems like you might have trouble with that. Using something like `ConcurrentDictionary<IPEndPoint, ClientInfo>` might be a better idea, but that really depends on what you're doing.

You could also explore some alternative options, like using asynchronous I/O instead of spamming threads, but that's a bit more advanced option (mind you, multi-threading is even worse :)). Regardless, a good start for thread-safety would be http://www.albahari.com/threading/ It's somewhat long, but multi-threading *is* a very complex and dangerous topic, and it will tend to produce errors that are hard to find and reproduce, especially while running in a debugger.

Comment: You are totally right about the static attributes. I removed it and everything works like a charm now. I do know what static means, but I do not know why I added it while creating the class. Thanks for that. I will definately do something about that Thread-safety. For now I am thinking about creating a sending thread with a kind of queue of messages to send. So this single Thread would repeatedly send messages if available but just one after another. I have a bit of personal war with understanding semaphors and locks, so I try to avoid them as far as possible.

Comment: @Eskalior Message queues are pretty much necessary when dealing with TCP, yeah. You can't really avoid locks when you're dealing with multi-threading, especially when using the `Thread` APIs. Due to how complex CPUs are nowadays (as in, the past 20 years or so :D), you can't even expect that setting a field on one thread will be seen on another thread. Any time you share state, you need to use some form of synchronization. Locks are the *simplest* kind of synchronization, apart from using the `Task` APIs (and `await`) in the safe (input -> output) way. Thread-safe collections help as well.